# XAML UI updates not visible in code-behind

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, intellisense, expression-blend

Having the same project opened in both, **Visual Studio** and **Blend**, I use the former to write code while I edit the XAML in the latter.

When I add an UI element to the .xaml file and save it in Blend, if I have that file opened in Visual Studio too, I see the message that some external changes have been done and asking if I want them to take effect in the opened file*. I accept it, and I can see the changes take effect in the .xaml file in Visual Studio.

The problem is, that although the new elements have been added to the .xaml file, I'm not able to access them throug Intellisense in the code-behind .cs file.

For example if I add following element to the *MainPage.xaml* using Blend:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="Button"/>
```

I can see that same line added to the page in Visual Studio, but I cannot access it using the name `MyButton` in *MainPage.xaml.cs* file. Intellisense is not working for it. If I write, for example `MyButton.Content = "Hello!";` it is red underlined, however I can build and run the project.

Rebuilding the project doesn't do the trick, and Intellisense doesn't work until I save the file "again" in Visual Studio.

I feel this behavior annoying sometimes, and I'd like to know if it is the normal behavior, or there is something wrong in my configuration.

**I usually don't have it opened in Visual Studio, just to avoid that meessage being shown for each modification in Blend*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just check your problem actually it is not a issue. everything is fine so what you have to do is save your xaml page on which you have added the button after accepting the changes that was done in blend..(do control + s on your xaml page one more time it will work fine)..sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Well... that's not a solution... Indeed, that's the annoying thing, that I have to save the file in Blend, Accept the changes in VS and re-save it in VS. I would expect that changes saved in Blend would take inmediate effect in VS (as they do, as I can see if I open the file), and I could avoid having the .xaml file opened in VS just to avoid having to accept each cange made through Blend.

Comment: look you can work in your blend without opening VS..but when you open it for work ..just save xaml..one time..you don't have to do it again and again..

Comment: If I have many .xaml files I would have to open all of them in VS just to save again. That's weird. I have a two screen configuration where I open Blend in one screen while I have VS in the other. That's far from my desired behavior.

Comment: look whatever you do in blend will work perfectly but when you want to try to access controls for doing some logic part on any xaml page.cs..then you have to do it..beside it every thing will work fine..

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when developing Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 2015 and somehow the problem went away after I:

1) Unload project (right-click project and select from context menu)

2) Edit .csproj (from context menu)

3) Pretend to modify and save csproj. :)

4) Reload project (from context menu)

Answer (score 0):

Closing the whole solution and re opening it fix my similar issue.